# is "keeps wanting to X" correct?

Tags: grammar

My wife, who teaches English to Spanish language students, but is not a native speaker insists that this sentence is wrong: My phone keeps wanting to switch to Spanish. She states the verb form of want here (with ing) must be intransitive and thus can't take an object. I can't help but think on this one she has the unusual distinction of being wrong, but she is alas usually right. So I turn to you fine folks for arbitrators: who is right and why? ;)

Comment: Your sentence is fine. I'm not sure where your wife is coming from. Is she thinking of the "lacking something" meaning as in "my phone was found wanting" ?

Comment: Merriam-Webster lists [six transitive uses](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/want), as [does AHD](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=want). Why *must* it be intransitive in your wife's opinion? I dislike using *want* with inanimate objects in this way, but that is just personal preference.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is "too basic". Maybe it should be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I must admit I don't understand the reasoning. Or rather, I am missing it altogether. We only have the conclusion that the verb must be transitive, but not how your wife arrived at it. *Why* must the verb be intransitive? And while we're at it: what would your wife say instead, then? Please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: When we call the phone "smart" and to some extent make it so, loading it with more programmed functions than the average user can know about, it comes to seem sufficiently sentient and often perverse to have its own peculiar preferences, a mind of its own. Lots of computer technology is like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine from that respect; there are several transitive senses of *want*, including the one used here. Indeed, the intransitive senses are probably the rarer.

Some would object to saying a phone "wants" something, as the phone lacks the sentience to desire anything. Personally while I think this metaphor can sometimes fail, as any metaphor can if combined in some unfortunate manner with another, it's too useful to abandon entirely, at least in informal use.